# .NET SmtpClient sending EHLO vs HELO

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, smtpclient

Running into a peculiar issue.  I have an SMTP server that I need to authenticate to in order to send mail.  We have a C# service that is designed to automatically do this, however the server host has configured the SMTP server to not allow relaying when a client initiates with HELO vs. EHLO.  When a client uses EHLO, relay is allowed.

Is there anyway to maintain SmtpClient use and send EHLO vs HELO?

Email response to HELO/EHLO relaying question from SMTP host provider:

> "By default our server is setup to authenticate to ehlo commands and
>   not helo. It will answer helo from hosts and delivery mail locally but
>   not relay."

Error from the application sent by the developer:

> 2011-09-14 14:32:17,764 ERROR ISearchService - An unhandled exception
>   was thrown while invoking
>   [AptitudeSolutions.OnCore.Services.ServiceAdapter.Search.SearchServiceAdapter].
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure
>   connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response
>   was: Relaying not allowed (enable smtp authentication on your email
>   client)    at
>   System.Net.Mail.RecipientCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode
>   statusCode, String response)    at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender,
>   MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify,
>   SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception)    at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)    at
>   AptitudeSolutions.OnCore.BusinessProcesses.Scenario.PublicRecordsNotification.AppServices.PublicRecordsNotificationEmailService.SendEmail(String
>   email, String subject, String body)    at
>   AptitudeSolutions.OnCore.BusinessProcesses.Scenario.PublicRecordsNotification.AppServices.PublicRecordsNotificationEmailService.SendNewAccountActivationEmailTo(String
>   email)    at
>   AptitudeSolutions.OnCore.BusinessProcesses.Scenario.PublicRecordsNotification.ServiceLayer.PublicRecordsNotificationServiceLayer.RequestNewAccount(NewAccountRequest
>   request)    at
>   AptitudeSolutions.OnCore.Services.ServiceAdapter.Search.SearchServiceAdapter.RequestNewNotificationAccount(NewAccountRequest
>   request)    at SyncInvokeRequestNewNotificationAccount(Object ,
>   Object[] , Object[] )    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)    at
>   AptitudeSolutions.Framework.DataAccessBase.Utility.Wcf.ServiceAttributes.ExceptionLoggingOperationInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)

Relevant part of config file:

```
  <system.net>
       <mailSettings>
         <smtp from="email@host.com">
              <network host="mail.smtphost.com" port="25" userName="username" password="password" defaultCredentials="false" />
         </smtp>
       </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

Some information has been edited for security purposes.

Comment: The docs aren't 100% clear on it, but it looks to me like setting EnableSSL to true will achieve this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc.aspx

Comment: .NET Framework 4.  I will try enabling ssl.  Thank you for the replies!

Comment: Doing some decompiling using dotPeek, it looks like EHLO is _always_ used, based on my reading of `SmtpConnection.GetConnection()`.  Are you sure it's **not** using EHLO?

Comment: @Coding Gorilla: Yes, EHLO is always used.  It think the OP has something backwards and certainly misconfigured.

Comment: @ChrisLively I would also add, that it seems very unusual to enable relay based on EHLO command, that would still leave your SMTP server as an open relay.  Possibly the OP is misunderstanding how is server is configured.  It's more typical that you need to supply logon credentials (which does also require EHLO) to enable relay.

Comment: @CodingGorilla: I completely agree.  mc.: can you post the relevant portion of your web.config AND the relevant part of your code that is sending the email?

Comment: I apologize, I'm a sys admin trying to help a developer who is writing this service -- they may not be using .NET 4 (if that makes a difference, however I AM using .NET 4).  I will edit the main post to include the information you requested.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the code that the developer has written, that is what I am trying to recreate at the moment.

Comment: Did you tried and recreate it?